# Android progress dialog disappears

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

I am new to android programming. So, I am trying to download a file from internet in async task and showing progress dialog until download finished. But if i switch my applications in between, say I open another app, progress dialog disappears.

This is the code I am using to show progress dialog

```
progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
progressDialog.setMessage("Backing Up...");
progressDialog.setMax(100);
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
progressDialog.show();
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Check all other references of progressDialog is your code. Maybe in onPause or onStop you may be dismissing the dialog

Comment: I am not using onPause, onStop anywhere in my applications

Comment: Ok. In that case you should override the onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState to handle the behavior. Can you post the rest of the code? Your activity may be getting recreated in the application switching.

Comment: Let me give it a shot, if it doesn't work for me, I'll post my code.

Answer (score 0):

First If you are using the asynctask it runs on UI Thread so you must be switching from the home button it puts your app on the pause you can override onPause and onResume methods

Comment: What is this, you are trying to give me? It's totally off the question. I know how to use Progress Dialog. I was looking for something else, read my question.

Comment: you said the progress dialog and asking for progress bar you must ask precisely

Comment: I have figured it out..check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding these methods in my code.

```
    @Override
            public void onDestroyView()
            {
                if (progressDialog != null && getRetainInstance())
                    progressDialog.setDismissMessage(null);
                super.onDestroyView();
            }
            @Override
            public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            }

@Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setRetainInstance(true);
        }
```